# Connect with Google Cloud MySQL through Python; how to access table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api-client, discovery

After following [this tutorial](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/tree/master/docs), I am able to run a script that prints all the details of my database. However, I have no clue as to how to do something with said database! Here's my code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery
import json

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
sqladmin = googleapiclient.discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', credentials=credentials)
response = sqladmin.instances().list(project='single-router-309308').execute()
print(json.dumps(

response, sort_keys=True, indent=2))
sqladmin.close()
```

Which prints all the info. I tried various things to reach my table, `products`, but I can't get it to work and keep getting a `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'execute'` (or `'list'`) exception. I tried stuff like this:

```
response = sqladmin.projects().list().execute()
```

To view my tables as well, but it doesn't work. I believe this is the correct approach since I can connect, but I haven't figured it out yet. Anybody know the answer?

Comment: The SQLAdmin api is intended for creating, editing and deleting Cloud SQL resources. So you can use it to create new SQL Server instances. It's not intended for working with the SQL server so much as working on it. I think you are more looking for https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview or https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, you should be able to get access to your table using the below code.

Note that you have an sql project, then an instance on the project, then a database in the instance, then your table is nested inside that database.

```
from pprint import pprint

# Project ID of the project that contains the instance.
project = 'single-router-309308'

# Database instance ID. You should have this from the above printout
instance = 'my-instance' 

# Name of the database in the instance. You can look this up if you arent sure by logging into google cloud for your project. Your table is inside this database.
database = 'my-database'

request = service.databases().get(project=project, instance=instance, database=database)
response = request.execute() #returns a dictionary with the data

pprint(response)
```

I would suggest you take a look at the REST API references for CLoud SQL for MySQL for further reading (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/databases/get).

Comment: Alright, it worked! I now get the information about my table. However, the documentation doesn't describe how to perform get / insert operations on the data, only on the database. Do you also know how to do that?

Comment: honestly i always resorted to using another library like sqlalchemy (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/connecting-to-cloud-sql-with-cloud-functions#2). The documentation says nothing which is strange, but I would guess you can execute as follows (given firebase structure): 

sqladmin.project('single-router-309308').database('[insert_database_name]').table('[insert_table_name]').get()

optionally providing the search parameters as arguments to get. firebase also has a function .to_dict() which is useful to convert the data from json format

Comment: I use sqlalchemy for my Functions as well, but couldn't get it to work for my VM / desktop. The received pymysql error doesn't help a lot either (Error: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")). Would you mind sharing how you managed to connect with sqlalchemy?